# Make cells visible in UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, cell

[image: First step[![][1]]][2[image: ]]I have a tableView with some content. There are all cells are showing perfectly. But after deleting a few rows, some cell's from below become invisible. I am deleting cells with method: `tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)`. But's they are has data and it height are good too. After a little time I found a solution: I changed the cell property of isHidden to false in `willDisplayCell` method. I dont think that is a good solution, but it worked. What do you think? Why are the cells not appearing?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return myFavoritesProductsDataSource.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "productCell") as! ProductTableViewCell
    cell.product = myFavoritesProductsDataSource[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let delete = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title:  "Удалить", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in 
    self.myFavoritesProductDataSource.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()
        success(true)
    })
    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [delete])
}
```

Comment: did you remove them from your data source? can you provide the code that you are using to delete the data from your data source? If you haven't removed them from you data source then this is happening because your cells are loaded from memory even after you deleted them.

Comment: @Nevin Jethmalani, "did you remove them from your data source?" - yes. I did. All another stuff work like a charm, except property  "isHidden" of tablView cell. All cells has it's own data. Just mechanism of displaying cell work not good. I must say that my tableView content is bigger than tableView. I mean that only 2 cell can be visible on screen. When i just scrolling (before delete some cells) all cells are visible and work good.

Comment: can you post the code for `cellForRowAt indexPath` and `numberOfRowsInSection`? and can you post the code for how you removed them from your datasource?

Comment: @Nevin Jethmalani, i am setting data in "willDisplaycell" method.

Comment: that is the first problem, you should be setting data in `cellForRowAt indexPath`. Can you post that code then?

Comment: i dont know how to put my code hear, because it's too big....)

Comment: you just copy and paste it. Just put a simplified version of the code so I know how you are setting your cell up and deleting rows. based on the information you have given, I cannot narrow down what you issue could be

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow - this might help

Comment: @Nevin Jethmalani, you was right about cellForRow!!!! I swear that i had read somewhere that better way to set data in willDisplay. But it was wrong. Now my cellFor looks like that:   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "productCell") as! ProductTableViewCell
        cell.product = myFavoritesProductsDataSource[indexPath.row];  return cell}

Comment: But it still doesn't help me. I need to put "cell.isHidden = false" for displaying.

Comment: @Nevin Jethmalani, func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {   return myFavoriteProductDataSource.count}

Comment: don't put your code here. edit your question and post the code in your question so when others need to look at this question, they can see your code there instead of reading the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `cellForRowAt indexPath` to set your data not `willDisplayCell`.

Here is the code formatted

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "productCell", for: indexPath) as! ProductTableViewCell 
    cell.product = myFavoritesProductsDataSource[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

When you delete the cell you should do it like this.

```
myFavoritesProductsDataSource.remove(at: indexPath.row)

self.tableView.beginUpdates()    
self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
self.tableView.endUpdates()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {

        myFavoritesProductsDataSource.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        self.tableView.beginUpdates()    
        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        self.tableView.endUpdates()

    }
}
```

Comment: But it still doesn't help me. I need to put "cell.isHidden = false" for displaying

Comment: once you delete the item from the datasource the way I did above, you don't need to have `cell.isHidden = false`

Comment: Nevin Jethmalani, yeah i have exactly the same code and it doesn't help me.

Comment: maybe try `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "productCell", for: indexPath) as! ProductTableViewCell ` instead of `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "productCell") as! ProductTableViewCell `

Comment: let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "productCell", for: indexPath) as! ProductTableViewCell - not helped :(

Comment: I am looking at your code? can you try getting rid of the last delegate function, `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt`. I didn't see where you put `self.tableView.deleteRows `

Comment: I putted it in handler of UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title:  "Удалить", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in  }); Swift 4.

Comment: Just saw it. I just made an update to my code. See if that help. Instead of using this delegate method, `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt `, use the one I have put above.

Comment: it's somehow connected with deleteAnimation. I am pretty sure.

Comment: Can you describe the problem in more detail. What exactly is happening? And can you include more relevant code. I have the exact same code in an app and it works perfectly so it is something else.

Comment: I will put some photo. I think main thing, that cell have a big content (like on photo), and dataSource must be more than 8 elements. And when you start delete cells, some cell become invisible.

Comment: I added some photo. On the first photo there are 8 elements in tableView. It's showing good. I can see all elements. After delete 3 elements(from top) i can see only 1 elements, but there are 5 elements! They are exist and fill with data. But only 1 thing dont let them show "cell.isHidden = true". And i never change this property by hand.

Comment: You need to post more code. I don’t see anything having to do with isHidden in the code you have posted.